# json output of an MVC Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, action

How can i preview the JSON output of an MVC Action that uses Jsonresult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) in conjuction with [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Firefox + Firebug to view the response

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the firefox Firebug plugin,

Or you can use some "proxiing" tool like TCPMon https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/ (java) or one is provided with MS SOAP toolkit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

i use this small piece of code to dump the json object

```
    function dump(obj) {
        var out = '';
        for (var i in obj) {
            out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
        }

        alert(out);

        // or, if you wanted to avoid alerts...

        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.innerHTML = out;
        document.body.appendChild(pre)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful.

[MVC.ApiExplorer](http://hg.digideas.com/mvc.apiexplorer/) is a portable, independent component that can help you to explore all actions of controller in an ASP.NET MVC project.